# When writing a Chrome Extension: How can I make sure the page fully loaded including the $(document).ready function on that page?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I've tried the `run_at="document_end"` but looks like both `$.ready` (the page,and my content script) trigger at the same time.

I have no control over the page script, only over my chrome extension.

Is there a way to fully wait for my script execution?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can use `$(window).load` in your script instead. then it will run after the `$(document).ready` of the page. the only downfall is that is also waits for graphics to load. but its what I use in my extenstions

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `run_at: document_idle` parameter for your content script? That will inject your script later than `document_end` would, immediately after the `window.onload` event fires.

Also see http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html#registration

Comment: It doesn't guarantee that it will fire after `window.onload` though, could be earlier.